# SQL select if condition applies

Tags: sql

I have 3 values:

- ObjectID
- User email
- User password

And two tables:

- Objects:

  - object id
  - user id
  - object name
- Users:

  - user id
  - email
  - password

I want to select object's name if:

- The user is valid (email and pass return row)
- and object belongs to the user or has a user id = 0 (belongs to everyone)
- object.id = ObjectID

What sql statement can get me that ?

Comment: I do not see a object name as mentioned in your question, is the object name part of your Objects table?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but should work.

```
SELECT 
    o.object_name 

FROM
    objects o
    LEFT JOIN users u ON o.user_id = u.user_id

WHERE
    o.objectId = 1
    AND (
        (u.email = ''
        AND u.password = '')
        OR o.user_id = 0
    )
```

Comment: The above SQL query returns all objects visible to the user, I'm looking for a single object that matches the ObjectID variable

Answer (score 1):

Return only the object name?

```
SELECT object_name 
FROM objects o LEFT JOIN users u ON o.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE (u.email IS NOT NULL
AND u.password IS NOT NULL) 
OR user_id = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT o.object_name FROM objects o
LEFT JOIN users u ON o.user_id=u.user_id
WHERE (u.email IS NOT NULL AND u.password IS NOT NULL)
OR o.user_id=0
```

I'm not sure if you meant object_name or object_id?

Comment: I'm passing object id and expecting object name in the query result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   o.Name
FROM
   Objects o
LEFT JOIN
   Users u
ON
   u.Id = o.UserId
WHERE
   (u.Email = email
AND
   u.Password = password)
OR
   o.UserId = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the objects in SqlFiddle if you want to test.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86023/9

```
SELECT O.ID FROM OBJECTS O

 WHERE O.ID IN  (
SELECT U.ID FROM USERS U
WHERE  U.USER = 'test' AND U.PASS = 'test'
)

OR O.USERID = 0
```